# Shopware6: Is there a way to get rid of 'Configure' menu item during Application update?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

Previously the application had only some simple Configuration page that was created during the installation process based on the description in config.xml file.

Now I want to switch to Meteor Admin SDK.
The idea was just to remove config.xml from the package and use proper settings in manifest.xml.
And it works correctly during the first installation of the package or if I perform uninstall->install.

But when just performing 'Update' from some previous version the menu item 'Configure' is left untouched (check the image attached with three options instead of the desired two options).
Of course, trying to open 'Configure' will lead to "*Encountered an error while loading the configuration:Configuration for scope "{{ $scope }}*" not found." error as far as there isn't actual config.xml anymore.

Is there some way how to remove this menu item during the update of the application?

[image: Three menu options]

Unfortunately, I can find only the information about adding configuration by config.xml but not about the ways how to deactivate it later without deinstallation :(